# How to get 1-minute data of just 1 day in Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, yahoo-api, yfinance, backtrader

```
yf.download("TSLA", start='2022-08-29', end='2022-08-30', interval="1m")
```

Above is the code that I normally use to get 1 minute stock prices of a period, but I want to get the prices for just 1 day. I cannot do it like the below.

```
yf.download("TSLA", start='2022-08-29', end='2022-08-29', interval="1m")
```

Below also does not work.

```
yf.download("TSLA", start='2022-08-29', period="1d", interval="1m")
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you be a bit more specific on what is the issue? 
With this command:

```
yf.download("TSLA", start='2022-08-26', period='1d', interval="1m")
```

I get the following output:
[All of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayuLp.png)

Only the first line is problematic, as it shows the data for the previous day. 
But this can be cleaned easily.

Comment: I was wondering if I could retrieve the data for just one day without having to edit the dataframe. But that's okay. I guess there's not a way.

Comment: Please add further steps to arrive to required answer by adding post processing steps to eliminate data apart from given day.